# Whats a shortcut way to extract the content of the .tar which is inside of the .tgz file? (windows)

Tags: windows, shortcuts

What is a shortcut way to extract the content of the .tar which is inside of the .tgz file? (For example by right-clicking and clicking extract, etc.)

I only ask because this seems to be a frequent format of certain downloads (video torrents) and I do not want to extrac the tgz, wait for the .tar to be extracted and then extract the .tar to the folder desired.

Answer (score 0):

[WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm) defaults to extracting the gzipped TAR in one step. The standard go-to program for compression, [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), unfortunately doesn't do it in a single step (yet), but you can double click the `tar.gz` and then open and extract the `tar` contained in it.

Apparently this is a matter of philosophy with the 7zip developers ([see here](https://superuser.com/questions/80019)). On Linux or OSX, you could just use `tar xvzf myfile.tar.gz`.